# grub-pc update failing

Tags: upgrade, apt

During the upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10, grub-pc failed to update.

```
dpkg: error processing grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
```

I have already tried `apt-get purge grub-pc` and reinstalling it, but the same error keeps coming up.

During the upgrade a few windows from Grub popped up asking me if I wanted to keep or replace the configuration files for Grub. I clicked the "keep" button on all of them. I suspect that might be the problem

Comment: Related: [Can't load GRUB all of a sudden (UEFI problem)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/240261/cant-load-grub-all-of-a-sudden-uefi-problem).  I've experienced the "failure" of `grub-pc` to update, but it may be a blessing on a UEFI-enabled system, in that grub might stop working if updated.