# Grub Setup for dual Ubuntu under EFI

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, secure-boot

I have installed to versions of Ubuntu, one up-to-date Xubuntu and a 12.04.5LTS Ubuntu. I first installed Xubuntu and later Ubuntu. Since the 12.04 would not write a correct grub-conf on install (I set up encryption for Xubuntu following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot)) i decided to let the grub conf on the `efi` partition load the grub conf from Xubuntus `/boot` partition. While I can now boot both OS's I get some errors about grub not being allowed to load some modules (`error: Secure Boot forbids loading module from (XX,YY)`).
I assume that this has something to do with efi and beeing signed. What is the easiest way to fix this? Can I simply reinstall grub from the Xubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/SecureBoot.
Reinstalling grub with the `--uefi-secure-boot` option fixed the problem for me.

```
sudo grub-install --uefi-secure-boot
```

Answer (score 0):

Most BIOSs allow you to turn off "secure boot" which should solve any of your problems related to unsigned modules.

FYI: My BIOS required me to set a BIOS password before it allowed me to change the "secure boot" setting, so I set it to something useless as a password, but easy to remember.

Comment: while I am sure that this would work I would prefer to update the signature file. That way I would keep the benefits of secure boot.

Comment: I didn't realise that you could even install GRUB with secure boot still enabled, neat.